# including views in a master view laravel 5.3

Tags: templates, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

It is my first app with laravel. I tried too much to follow template rules to implement them in my app but actually I don't know did it in a correct way or not. Using the way I did, when I need to `Redirect` to a previous page it backs to `/` page and for example when I need to stay on the same page after submitting a form, I can not `make` the specific view or maybe I don't know how to use it. Do you think implementation is correct or not?

This is my master view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="rtl">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ $page_title }}</title>

    {{ Html::style('css/styles.css') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/core/app.js') }}

</head>

<body>
            <!-- Header -->
    @include('header')
            <!-- Header -->

            <!-- Sidebar -->
    @include('sidebar')
            <!-- Sidebar -->

            <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div id="container"></div>`
    </div>
            <!-- /main content -->
</body>
</html>
```

This is my typicall included view:

```
@extends('Content_template')

@section('pageContents_js_files')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset("js/validate.min.js") }}"></script>
@stop

@section('pageContents')
    <div></div>
@endsection
```

And this is a piece of html that is attached to all the typical views:

```
@yield('pageContents_style_files')

@yield('pageContents_js_files')


    <!-- Page header -->
    <div></div>
    <!-- /page header -->


    <!-- Content area -->
    <div class="content">

        <!-- Page Contents -->
        @yield('pageContents')
        <!-- /Page Contents  -->

        <!-- Footer -->
        @include('footer')
        <!-- Footer -->
    </div>
    <!-- /content area -->
```

I am using ajax to include views to master template when an `<a>` tag with `include` class is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".include").click(function(event)
    {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'include/' + $(this).attr('id'),
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    $data = $(data);
                    $('#container').html($data);
                }
            });
        //}
    });
});
```

And finally the route (all the views are stored in pages directory):

```
Route::get('include/{param}',function($param){
    return view('pages.'.$param);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary to use ajax. Just yield all `js` an `css` files to master blade, also yield other pages to master, then you can call them through routes.

Comment: Really thanks [farzad pakzad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5033994/farzad-pakzad) . I hadn't noticed that point. It was simple.